# revolution slider wordpress fullscreen and container offset

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to use the revolution slider plugin in wordpress, but it doesn't work correctly

The web site is visible at this url : [the web site](http://leburo.ideesimple.net)

My configuration in edit slider:

Slider Layout : Full screen

Offset containers: #blocRslider  (my div who is redim on resize window with another script in window resize in my script.js)

[screenshot](http://www.ideesimple.net/dev/screenPrint.html)

And in the edit slides the background setting is:

Background fit: contain

The layer animation does not slide in the height of my container. Why?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you seem to have a set height for the slider instead of using a percentage.

There should be a setting to amend the slider height which i think is currently set to 80px, if you increase this to either 520px or 100%, it will stop the problem of the small image.

Next, change the background-fit this:

```
background-size: cover;
```

This will make the background cover the entire area within its container.